# Reformat Python List

Tags: python, mysql, list, format, mysql-connector

I'd like to convert a python list `[1,2,3]` to a structure like `((1),(2),(3))` for a MYSQL execution.

My current version looks like

```
mySQLconnection = connectMyDatabase() #def connectMyDatabase() has been tested and works
cursor = mySQLconnection.cursor()

list = [...]
sql_query = "DELETE FROM multiusingfuncs WHERE muf_id IN (%s) " % ','.join(['?'] * len(list))
cursor.execute(sql_query, list)
```

which produces error message

```
ValueError: Could not process parameters
```

Thank's for any advice.

Comment: Try `print(sql_query)` after creating it, and see what is wrong with it.

Comment: You need to replace the `?` with `%s`.

Comment: print(sql_query) gives 

DELETE FROM multiusingfuncs WHERE muf_id IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: See my comment above. `?` is not the parameter place holder to be used for prepared statements with MySql. ` ... join(['%s'] ...`

Comment: Thank's, did work with your proposal.